# Blazor component <select> changed event not firing

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm new to Blazor and can't seem to figure out why my component event handler doesn't seem to fire. I'm using .NET 8 and the sample template configured to:

- Interactive render mode: **Auto (Server and WebAssembly)**
- Interactive location: **Per page/component**

In the server project, in the 'Components/Pages' folder, I have a component called `DropDownFilter.razor` with the following code:

**DropDownFilter.razor**

```csharp
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<div>
    <span>
        <select @bind="Item">
            @foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                <option value="@item">@item</option>
            }
        </select>
    </span>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public List<string> Items { get; set; } = [];

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<List<string>> ItemsChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Item { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ItemChanged { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a component `SearchFilters.razor`:

**SearchFilters.razor**

```csharp
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h3>Search Filters</h3>

<section>
    <div>
        <DropDownFilter ItemChanged="MakeChanged" @bind-Items="Makes" />
    </div>
</section>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Make { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    private List<string> Makes { get; set; } = ["Audi", "BMW", "Volvo"];

    private void MakeChanged(string make)
    {
        // This method is never called.
        this.Make = make;
    }

}
```

Then, my `Home.razor` looks like this:

**Home.razor**

```html
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SearchFilters/>
```

The problem I have is that the `MakeChanged()` method in the `SearchFilters.razor` component never seems to fire. I've tried it with both `string` and `ChangedEventArgs`, but neither seem to work.

My understanding is that the `@bind` expects an implied and corresponding `EventCallback<> ...Changed()` handler, e.g. `@bind="MyItem"` and the implied handler `EventCallback<> MyItemChanged()`. I guess that I could try wiring these up explicitly, but I was hoping to take advantage of the new features of Blazor.

Clearly my solution is going to be more complex, with multiple `DropDownFilter` components whose contents will be determined based on the choice made in the previous one, and their values being drawn from an API, but I've simplifying my test down to this example.

There's obviously something I'm missing, and would be grateful for a pointer in the right direction.

Thanks,

Kaine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from "@MrC aka Shaun Curtis" putting me on the right track, the solution was:

**DropDownFilter.razor**

```csharp
<div>
    <span>
        <select @bind="Item" @bind:after="OnItemChanged">
            @foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                <option value="@item">@item</option>
            }
        </select>
    </span>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public List<string> Items { get; set; } = [];

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<List<string>> ItemsChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Item { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ItemChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnItemChanged()
    {
        await this.ItemChanged.InvokeAsync(this.Item);
    }

}
```

It seems that, while **requiring** a callback event property matching the property name used in the `@bind` attribute (e.g. if the bind property is `MyItem` then the callback event property *must* be called `MyItemChanged`), the callback event property isn't fired automatically when the bound property value is changed. Instead, the `@bind:after` attribute can be used to call another event handler, which itself can then be used to invoke the callback event property after the bound value has changed.

So, in the chain of events:

1. The `select` is bound to a property (let's call it `MyItem`) using the `@bind` attribute, e.g. `@bind="MyItem"`.
2. A corresponding matching callback event property called `EventCallback<T> MyItemChanged` *must* be created, where `T` is the type of `MyItem`, a `string` in this case.
3. In order to get the corresponding `EventCallback<T> MyItemChanged` to fire , it has to be invoked manually. The trigger for this can be called using the `@bind:after` attribute, which in this case is mapped to a new event handler method I have called `OnItemChanged()` (which strictly speaking should probably called `OnMyItemChanged()` to fit in with what's being explained here, but could quite easily have been called anything I liked).

I hope that's clear, reading it back, my explanation seems a little confusing, but hopefully the example speaks for itself.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't binding correctly in DropDownFilter.  In your code you are just changing the value of `Item`.  You need to set up the two way binding separately.

```cs
<div>
    <span>
        <select @bind:get="Item" @bind:set="this.OnItemChanged">
            @foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                <option value="@item">@item</option>
            }
        </select>
    </span>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public List<string> Items { get; set; } = [];
    [Parameter] public string Item { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> ItemChanged { get; set; }

    private Task OnItemChanged(string value)
    {
        return this.ItemChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
```

You can then

```cs
<DropDownFilter ItemsChanged="Makees" @bind-Item="Make" />
```

If you want to flow the Make down to the parent you need to do the same with the get and set as I've sown above.

Also note: You should not be setting the render mode on individual components. A component such as DropDownFilter should be rendermode agnostic: you can use it anywhere. Either set it at the page/form level or the global level. See the note in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#apply-a-render-mode-to-a-component-definition

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I'll give your suggestions a try, thank you.

It was my understanding that using the `@bind` as it is was enough to require a corresponding event handler. I'm still not quite sure why this isn't enough though.

Re the rendermode directives, that was me trying all sorts and trying to eliminate any complexity, but thx again for your guidance. 

Once I've tried it out, I'll report back.